# Compartilhar uma tabela para dois bancos de dados diferentes na versão 9.4

Tags: postgresql

Boa tarde , estamos tentando fazer um gatilho em laboratório  do nosso sistema  , Estamos no momento tentando  fazer que as bases  mesmo distintas  compartilhem  a tabela produto  , ai funcionaria  assim   toda alteração feita na tabela em uma base alterava  na outra  , teria como fazer isso ? Desde já obrigado

Essas são as tabelas
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E essa é a tabela que eu quero vê se tem como compartilhar  com o outro banco.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: use dblink : http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html

Comment: Para esta versão (de 2014) a única solução é o dblink, avalie se realmente atende a suas necessidades. Em versões mais recentes existe a possibilidade de usar um Foreign Data Wrapper.

Comment: Não sei quais são os requisitos de sua(s) aplicação(ões) mas você já avaliou se o uso de diferentes  schemas, no lugar de diferentes bancos de dados, não seria mais adequado ao seu ambiente já que você quer compartilhar tabelas?